# Calendar+ does not automatically update subscribed calendars

Tags: owncloud

I'm using ownCloud and its Calendar+ application.
This application is really great as it allows me to include external (ical) calendars. However, it seems as if the subscribed calendars are not refreshed automatically. New events on the subscribed calendars are not automatically visible in Calendar+.
Question 1: is there a way to automatically refresh subscribed calendars?

One of the subscribed calendars is my "Upcoming Events" calendar from Facebook. When creating the ical subscription, all the event have been included pretty flawlessly, but now there are new events in this calendar which won't be synched (as already mentioned in Question 1).
When manually refreshing the calendar, the update fails (Just "Update failed") without any detailed description. Does anyone have the same issues? Is there a workaround?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a piece of software, not about programming.

Comment: I don't get the issue. Also in the normal calendar app you can import ical's. Maybe you can show an image to make your issue much clearer. And yes I think this is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not referring to an ICAL file which is imported once and then all the events are available in owncloud. I wolle like to subscribe to some kind of dynamic calendar. For example, I would like to see all my facebook events. Therefore I include my facebook calendar as external calendar. All my currently existing events are shown then. So far, so good. But when creating a new event in facebook, this newly created event is then not synched to owncloud. If you think, this question is of-topic, I'll delete it. I would just like to wait another day, just in case you know the answer to my question:)

Comment: Maybe you find some other ideas on my tutorial here: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/